# Django Admin Display row if a variable is true

Tags: django

I'm fairly new to Django and I'm implementing the admin.py file. I was wondering if it was possible to put an if statement in the admin.py file. What I want to do is display a row in my database only if a certain variable is true. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override `ModelAdmin.queryset()` (or `ModelAdmin.get_queryset()` for 1.6+)

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self):
        qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset()
        if True:  # however you get your condition
           return qs.filter()  # whatever rows need to be included
        return qs.filter()
```

Comment: This is right, but note that on Django versions earlier than the development branch this method was called simply `queryset`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper - nice catch! I barely noticed / just referenced the docs. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, so the if statement checks to see if the condition is satisfied? Do you put any arguments then in qs.filter()?

Comment: `user1998511` Since you have not shared your condition nor your filter, I can only provide a template for you to modify. "What I want to do is display a row in my database only if a certain variable is true" - yes, fill in the filters to get the results you need.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita So I want to display all rows in my database if a variable for that row is true. So if a variable `a` is true for row 1 but not row 2, I display row 1 but not row 2.
Could I not just fill in qs.filter() and not need the if statement?

Comment: That's a standard filter. As easy as Model.objects.filter(variable=True). Exactly, no need for an if statement. Your question did not make the source of the condition clear.

Comment: Ok thanks! So I put this in my admin class along with the table initializations?

Comment: This is a method of your admin class, yes - I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'along with the table initializations'.  By default, an admin class covers all instances of its registered model.  By overriding the default method, you can filter which instances are covered.  Just for one example, it's common to use something like this to limit the admin to covering objects owned by the current user, assuming you track that on your model - `return qs.filter(owner=request.user)`.