# django admin - Separation by type in one model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

users/models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "user"

user_nm = models.CharField(max_length=10)
user_email = models.EmailField( unique=True)
user_tel = models.CharField(
    max_length=11, validators=[validate_user_tel]
)
user_ty = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

users/admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        "id",
        "user_nm",
        "user_ty",
        "user_tel",
        "user_email",
        "point_amt",
        "user_join_dts",
    ]
```

There are two types of user models(user_ty) "P" and "G".

at the admin
I want to divide categories by users "P" and "G" types. Will it be possible?

[image]

For example, an existing administrator is a capture.
Each model in the board app is listed.
What I want is to give the [user_ty] field in the user's app "G" and "P" respectively, just like each model.

Comment: You can add a [List Filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) to `UserAdmin` like this: `list_filter = ('user_ty',)` Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @evergreen  Before the filter, I want to separate "user_ty" into categories. Like the models listed on the admin main page. :)

Comment: @evergreen I added it, but I don't know if it's explained well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the same model twice in Django admin, you need to use the proxy model, something like this [enter link description here][1] and then you can show the model in admin based on condition like this [enter link description here][2]

[1]: [https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/add_model_twice.html#:~:text=%C2%B6,only%20the%20read%20only%20admin.](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/add_model_twice.html#:%7E:text=%C2%B6,only%20the%20read%20only%20admin.))
[2]: [Django Admin Display row if a variable is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926261/django-admin-display-row-if-a-variable-is-true)